# Dataset not being accepted by Weka's J48 plugin (C 4.5 algorithm)

Tags: weka, j48, c4.5

I have a "diabetes" dataset with all scalar fields I want to run the C 4.5 algorithm on. When I have it loaded in Weka, the J48 option for decision trees is not selectable. I found a "bank data" dataset online that has 2 scalar fields and 8 categorical fields, which the J48 option is selectable and runs fine.

I thought C 4.5 did not need containerization for its input, which seems to be the only difference between the selectable and non-selectable datasets. What type of preprocessing do I need to perform on the "diabetes" dataset to make it acceptable to the J48 plugin/C 4.5 algorithm?

Comment: J48 requires a nominal/categorical class attribute. What is yours?